# How do you build out a folder hierarchy when installing TFS 2018 on premises?

Tags: tfs

I am installing TFS 2018 on premises and I want to try to enforce some logical folder structure where all of the deposit related projects\development are in the Deposits folder. All of the lending in Lending etc. etc.

I created two collections one for testing of the tfs installation and a production collection. It seems you can only create Team Projects in a collection. Is there no way to create a hierarchy?

Or how about a sub project? I don't want to have a team project for every single task. Some tasks are tiny while others are large multi programmer projects. And if I create a Team project for say Deposits and have folders for each task\project then won't I lose the extensive amount of ALM features for projects? I mean, won't they comingle when they are all under one project?

I must be missing something. Even sourcesafe allowed you to create a working folder. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchies are established within team projects. A team project is a *portfolio of related applications*.

Use [teams, iterations, and area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops) within a single team project for organization of work items. Iterations define your schedule for work, and area paths allow for organization of work items for filtering and assignment to specific teams.

For source code, if you're using TFVC, you can either create folders within a single team project and enforce access via security settings, or create separate team projects for each unrelated suite of applications.

A typical TFVC structure within a team project would be something along the lines of

- $/MyTeamProject

  - /ApplicationX

    - /Main (trunk)
    - /Dev (branch from Main)
  - /ApplicationY

    - /Main (trunk)
    - /Dev (branch from Main)

Or if ApplicationX and Y are related and need to be branched together, you invert the structure:

- $/MyTeamProject

  - /Main (trunk)

    - ApplicationX
    - ApplicationY
  - /Dev (branch from Main)

    - ApplicationX
    - ApplicationY

For Git, you can either keep unrelated applications in separate repositories, or adopt a monorepo approach. Each approach has advantages and disadvantages and will require you to do some research to decide which one fits your use-case.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow even though I have utilized it for years so I am not sure if I am allowed to thank you for such an awesome answer. You really cleared up the issue quite well for me. We are still on SourceSafe and after 12 yrs it is a mess. I so wanted to start TFS off right and you're answer helps out tremendously.

Comment: @mtaylor764 when you have sufficient reputation, you can upvotr answers like this. That is the general thank you mechanism.